# Efficient compression of mmap'd cache

Tags: c++, arrays, caching, mmap

Hi have a piece of code utilizing `mmap()` in GNU/Linux written in C/C++ that writes data arrays to a preallocated mmap. I'm not sure I'm using the right terms. These are variable sized arrays and I am using a union to make each element of data fit nicely no matter the underlying type. Each data array stores an offset (elsewhere, not relevant) that can be used to access the beginning of the data, the array length is also stored there.

As each data array is added to the mmap-backed cache, it is appended at the end position of the last written array. This all works fine. When deleting or reassigning the element, I am simply invalidating it in the "pointer" that stores the mmap offset and length and writing another new element to the cache.

As elements are changed or deleted, the cache is ever growing. Here is my question, what is the best way to compress these invalidated and obsolete arrays in C or C++? (I am thinking in terms of C as this is working with raw bytes.) Please, I am only asking for suggestions on how to remove and compress the data when an array is invalidated to avoid fragmentation or wastefulness. I am looking for the most efficient way.

Also note, this requires GCC 4.4.7 for the time being, so I can only use C99 and C++98.

A small sample of code for what I am doing to give you the idea of how data is being added:

```
// Get the offset position in mmap for writing
void *vPtr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(CardCache + getCardCacheFixedDataSize() + offset);
ElementList list;
memcpy(vPtr, &list, sizeof(ElementList));

ElementList *dataPtr = reinterpret_cast<ElementList*>(vPtr);
ElementData *data = reinterpret_cast<ElementData*>(malloc(count*sizeof(ElementData)));
dataPtr->count = (size_t)count;

for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    data[i].i = intList[i];
}
memcpy(&dataPtr->data, &data[0], count*sizeof(ElementData));
free(data);

// "point" to the data
currPtr->key = key;
currPtr->offset = offset;

// advance the writing offset to the next position.
cardCacheVarWriteOffset += reqsize;
```

Comment: You are looking for a heap compaction algorithm.  Here is an interesting overview, http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~fischer/cs536.s08/lectures/Lecture31.4up.pdf.  You may also want to look up 'mark and sweep' algorithms

Comment: Awesome. I will take a look!